# Is it possible to use arithmetic in scala matchers?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider the code:

```
def MatchSmth(someInt: Int, offset: Int = 1): Int  = {
  someInt match {
    case `offset` + 3 => 123123
    case `offset` + 4 => 22
    case `offset` + 5 => 123
    case invalid => -1
  }
 }
```

Compilation error: `scala not found: value +`

Equivalent1:

```
def MatchSmth(someInt: Int, offset: Int = 1): Int  = {
  if (someInt == offset + 3) 123123
  else if (someInt == offset + 4) 22
  else if (someInt == offset + 5) 123
  else -1
 }
```

Equivalent2:

```
def MatchSmth(someInt: Int, offset: Int = 1): Int  = {
  someInt match {
    case v if v == `offset` + 3 => 123123
    case v if v == `offset` + 4 => 22
    case v if v == `offset` + 5 => 123
    case invalid => -1
  }
 }
```

Is there something similar to this code except equivalent1 and equivalent2? Why does Scala not allow such construction (with arithmetic) in matchers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Technical reason

Technically Scala does not allow it in its specification. This is already described in the [answer from Suma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28168383/1885392).

## Conceptual reason

Conceptually, the idea of pattern matching is not to be a nice shortcut for if-then-else or to solve equations but to provide define partial functions using destructuring, similar to [Lisp](http://dunsmor.com/lisp/onlisp/onlisp_22.html). For this task, Scala uses so called "extractors".

An extractor is kind of the opposite of an constructor. Technically Scala uses the method "unapply" to decompose a given object in its parts. Unapply takes the object and returns either a boolean, an optional atomic value or an optional tuple. Alternatively there is also unapplySeq, which can return a sequence of values. Scala then tries to match the result to the given parameter list. When a match is possible, Scala unfies the atomic value or the part of the tuple with the given parameter name. (see [this paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf) for more details)

Example:

```
case class Pet(name: String, age : Int)
Pet("Polly", 86) match {
   case Pet(name, _) => println(s"Hello ${name}")
}
// This will print: Hello Polly
```

Scala will create an object `Pet("Polly", 86)`. It will then give that object to the partial function defined after the `match`. This function will call `Pet.unapply(...)` on that object and check whether the result is of the shape `Some(Tuple[Int,_])`. If true, it will bind the variable `name` to the first member of that tuple and call the given action with the `println` function.

Scala only checks the shape of the result of `unapply`. In theory it could put more effort in trying to unify the result of unapply with the given variables. This would help in simple cases like the one in your example. But it will come with a huge runtime penalty in more complex cases. In theory, unification could even go in an endless loop.

## Summary (tl;dr)

Match is not a fancy if, but uses destructuring. It doesn't put any effort in unification, but takes the terms "as-is". This is necessary to keep the generated code fast.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what "unification" is and why unification can be done against a literal, but not against a result of expression?

Comment: Unification is what Prolog does to match two terms. Wikipedia has a good explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29 Unification is a great tool for abstraction. Unfortunately it comes with a huge runtime penalty (and in some cases it never finishes).

Comment: Even after reading that I cannot see the runtime penalty for this case. What we are talking here are just combination of literals, variables with known values and function calls. All of this can be computed in a normal way, same as when a program is executed. I do not see any difference when unifying with a result of computation or unifying with a variable value (which is already possible). I understand it may be not trivial to define the grammar, and as the use case is not very important, it is not likely to happen. but I am not convinced runtime penalty is the reason.

Comment: @Suma: Your case is fine and comes without a runtime penalty. But slightly more useful cases come with a huge penalty. So this feature would only be useful for very simple cases and then fails for slightly more complex cases. Even when you restrict unification to arithmetic cases, you would easily run into complex cases that Scala cannot easily solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
def MatchSmth(someInt: Int, offset: Int = 1): Int  = {
   (someInt - offset) match {
       case 3 => 123123
       case 4 => 22
       case 5 => 123
       case _ => -1
   }
}
```

Comment: This post should be the answer for question1. Great, simple and obvious. But I was interested in theoretical solution with more complex arithmetic operations, so Suma's answer more suitable for me. I'd have chosen both if I can.

Answer (score 1):

No. The [Scala grammar](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for pattern is:

> #### 8.1 Patterns
>
> ```
> Syntax:
> Pattern       ::= Pattern1 { ‘|’ Pattern1 }
> Pattern1      ::= varid ‘:’ TypePat
>               | ‘_’ ‘:’ TypePat
>               | Pattern2
> Pattern2      ::= varid [‘@’ Pattern3]
>               | Pattern3
> Pattern3      ::= SimplePattern
>               | SimplePattern {id [nl] SimplePattern}
> SimplePattern ::= ‘_’
>               | varid
>               | Literal
>               | StableId
>               | StableId ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’
>               | StableId ‘(’ [Patterns ‘,’] [varid ‘@’] ‘_’ ‘*’ ‘)’
>               | ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’
>               | XmlPattern
> Patterns      ::= Pattern {‘,’ Patterns}
> ```

As you can see, `literal` (8.1.4 Literal Patterns) or a `StableId` (8.1.5 Stable Identifier Patterns) is allowed, not a constant expression. You could ask now - is there some significant reason why constant expression are not allowed? Would the grammar still work unambiguously if constant expression was allowed? That I do not know.

Comment: stefan.schwetschke answer was more complete, but yours is a good one, too.